# Entity Framework Does not Import Table with Super Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, many-to-many

I have 4 tables:

[image]

but when I create an entity framework model, why is `tblRoleInProfile` not generated?

[image]

I have a Linq TO SQL model that want to convert it to EF and now my table is not generated. How can I solve that?

**UPDATE 1:**

You consider we have some profiles and some roles. If we want Profile A has role 1 Insert a record in `tblRoleInProperty` and if we want Profile B has not Role 2 (If it exists) delete it's record from `tblRoleInProperty`. I don't want delete a profile. another problem is select new projection. Can any body guide me to write this query in EF:

```
var prs = from p in dc.tblProfiles
          join rp in dc.tblRoleInProfiles
              on p.ProfileId equals rp.ProfileId
          join r in dc.tblRoles
              on rp.RoleId equals r.RoleId
          select new
          {
              ProfileName = p.ProfileName,
              ProfileId = p.ProfileId,
              RoleName = r.RoleName,
              RoleId = r.RoleId
          };
```

Thanks

Comment: It appears to have been replaced with the new Many-To-Many relationship between tblRole and tblProfile. Guessing the wizard found that table to be redundant. Not sure how to "force" it to create it otherwise.

Comment: @Pepto:It so bad.Now How I can Join my tables?It shouldn't guess what is redundant or not :(:(:(:(

Comment: See Ninja's comment below for a work-around to this problem. I just don't use import wizards stuff enough to answer the 'why'...Also, if you are looking for 1 to 1 table to class you should probably be using LINQ to SQL Classes instead of EF

Comment: @Pepto:It's Bug.I don't know when microsoft'bug finished.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how EF works. EF is ORM tool - it tries to hide persistance details and junction table in many-to-many relation is exactly that detail you don't want to see in your object model.

You can rewrite your query simply to:

```
var prs = from p in dc.tblProfiles
          from r in p.tblRoles
          select new
              {
                  ProfileName = p.ProfileName,
                  ProfileId = p.ProfileId,
                  RoleName = r.RoleName,
                  RoleId = r.RoleId
              };
```

Updating and deleting relations also works through navigation properties.

Inserting role to profile:

```
// Dummy objects so you do not need to load them from DB first. 
// These objects must exist in database
var p = new Profile { ProfileId = ... };
var r = new Role { RoleId = ... };

context.tblProfiles.Attach(p);
context.tblRoles.Attach(r);

p.tblRoles.Add(r);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Deleting role from profile:

```
// Dummy objects so you do not need to load them from DB first. 
// These objects must exist in database
var p = new Profile { ProfileId = ... };
var r = new Role { RoleId = ... };

p.tblRoles.Add(r);

context.tblProfiles.Attach(p);
context.tblRoles.Attach(r);

p.tblRoles.Remove(r);
// another approach: 
// context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeRelationshipState(p, r, x => x.tblRoles, EntityState.Deleted);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka:Thanks,but this leads to CROSS JOIN that has very heavy cost.

Comment: @Nima: No this leads to INNER JOIN because second `from` does not select from "table" but from navigation property of the first `from`.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka:GREATE,Yes this works.Can help me in UPDATE 1 in my question?delete a row from linked table

Comment: @Nima: Btw. you can manually modify diagram to include junction table as entity but it is bad way to work with EF.

Comment: I don't like the way EF hides join tables. First of all it seems very unintuitive to me. And when mapping data model to your business classes, this introduces unnecessary dependency (actually role shouldn't depend on profile, but it still contains a reference to collection of profiles).

Comment: @Kniga: You don't have to expose that collection in the role if you don't want the dependecy. It just default setting.

Answer (score 2):

> but when I create an entity framework
>   model Why tblRoleInProfile not
>   generated?

Entity Framework correctly identified the table representing a pure many-to-many relationship between `tblProfile` and `tblRole`. This relationship is now expressed through the navigation properties in those two tables. When you access the navigation property, EF will do a join for you internally to return the right related entities to you - in the end this will lead to much cleaner queries since you don't need to express the join explicitly anymore.

As for your example I would reconsider the tbl prefix on your tables / entities - It really hurts readability.

Comment: thanks.You say:`When you access the navigation property EF will do a join for you internally to return the right related entities to you` how I can access navigation property and can you show me an example that EF does JOIN?

Comment: A new problem is how to delete a record from `tblRoleInProperty`?

Comment: @Nima: you mean the `tblRoleInProfile` table? You should have cascading delete setup for this, so that if you delete an entity from `tblProfile` the corresponding entries in `tblRoleInProfile` are deleted automatically.

Comment: @Nima: The navigation property represents the join - so when you i.e. do a `context.tblProfile.First().tblRoles` this will return all `tblRoles` that will only return the related roles for this one profile.

Comment: Please See Update 1 in Main Question

Answer (score 1):

You can change your table to hold an extra ID column instead of the superkey. I know it's not neccessary, but that way EF will definitely import it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you shouldn't do anything. Your entities are Role and Profile. You'd want to use the relationships created between the entities.

```
var db = new Entities(); //whatever your context name is
var r = new Role{RoleName="Rtest"};
var p = new Profile {ProfileName = "PTest"};
p.Roles.Add(r);
db.Profiles.AddObject(p);
db.SaveChanges();
```

EF will take care of the rest. I know you have work invested in L2S, but you may find your life easier if you follow the EF happy path and makes some changes instead of forcing EF to look like LINQ to SQL.

You can query like this:

```
var qu = from r in dc.tblRoles 
         where r.tblProfiles.Any(p=> p.ProfileId == 42)
         select r;

foreach (var r in qu) {
    Console.WriteLine(r.RoleName)
    foreach (var p in r.tblProfiles) {
       Console.WriteLine(p.ProfileName)
   }
 }
```

Comment: @Rob:My problem not in Insert.How I can Join Role and Profile?

Comment: Each entity will have a Relationship. Profile will have a Roles (or tblRoles) property and Role will have a Profiles (tblProfiles) property.

Comment: they have property but I cant write this query:`var qu = from r in dc.tblRoles
                         where r.tblProfiles.ProfileId
                         ????` or `from r in dc.tblRoles
                         join p in dc.tblProfiles
                         on ????` ?

Comment: I can't access fields of another tables using their property

Comment: @rob:thanks but you use sub query and not join.I want to use join

Comment: Can I ask why you feel compelled to use the join keyword. Keep in mind that the Linq query and the T-SQL query are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution was to insert a column to the relationship table:

```
tblRoleInProfile (
    ProfileId int not null,
    RoleId int not null,
    UpdateDate DateTime not null
)...
```

dont actually needed the column in my case, but it serves the purpose